# Is "paiement" an english word?

Tags: loanwords

I'm wondering if the `paiement` word is an English word. It looks like a French word.

Could you confirm that `paiement` is an English word?

Comment: Have you tried using one of the dictionaries suggested by http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2574/1420 ?

Comment: No, it's not. It's a French word and means *payment*. In any event, this is a GR; voting to close. **Effectuer un paiement. Le paiement des impôts.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Paiement* is a French word, English word is ***Payment***.

Such words are used a lot in Louisiana(and other places which were French colonies or places closer to France).

Comment: "Such words are used a lot in Louisiana"? Do you mean such a **spelling** is used in **English** writing in Louisiana?

Comment: Yes, it is used in legal terms. `DATION EN PAIEMENT`, civil law. One of the official/native languages in Louisiana is French, other is English.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr, there is no official language in Louisiana but you're right that French is one of two defacto administrative languages, the other being English, of course, with over 90% of the population using English as their first language and under 5% claiming French as their first language . . . according to Wikipedia - to be taken with a *"grain de sel, naturellement!* :-)

Comment: My comment asks "in English writing," not French. You should have actually answered 'No.' :)

Comment: Ohh!! My bad @Kris, Fridays are always too much to take for me.